# How to solve This Breadth-First Search Question

Tags: search

So my professor in college gave us a quiz, using Breadth-First Search , I answered this question as follows:-
**S -> {A,B} -> {C,D,E} -> {G2}**

since we found the goal then we stop , so the answer is d(otherwise)
however the professor gave us the answer as b.

Can anyone explain why and how to solve this type of questions ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I just saw that you ended at G2 as opposed to G1. (At first I thought the problem was you wanting to return an answer as a list of lists.)

I would agree with you that the answer is (D). G2 is discovered as a neighbor of D, before G1 is discovered as a neighbor of E.

I don't see how one would arrive at G1 first, unless doing something weird like sorting on insertion into the queue.

Comment: Yeah , I was just communicating with other students in same course and we reached the same answer , probably a mistake in professor answer , I guess.
Just wanted to make sure that I didn't make some stupid mistake while solving it and can't notice it.